Not able to access MySQL azure db from my local while being connected to VPN
I am able to access my mysql azure database from the VM which has been installed with pritunl server and both db and VM are in the same Vnet. But when I connect to the same user in VPN and try accessing my db (using its server name) from my local I get this error.
`Server:        8.8.8.8
Address:    8.8.8.8#53
** server can't find ra********.com: NXDOMAIN`
I have added all this 8.8.8.8, 1.1.1.1, 1.0.0.1 in my pritunl DNS server on browser.

The reason is that you are asking a public DNS server (google in your example) for the domain ra*****.com that you probably use it only internally in your environment. Is this the case ? Is it a public available domain ? The NXDOMAIN suggest that it is not.
Try first to connect using the IP of the mysql database from your host while connected with pritunl, if it works you can add temporaly the proper entry on your machine host file (as an intermediate solution)
